# Feedback about JDBC Type 4 Driver for Microsoft Access

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

we need some data which is stored on several Microsoft Access databases on our servers, and our application will be executed on a Linux machine.

So, our only alternative consist in using a JDBC Type 4 driver. In our research, we found two alternatives:

- HXTT - http://www.hxtt.com/access.html
- StelsMDB - http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_mdb_jdbc.htm

Has anyone here ever used one of these? How was your experience?
Are they really good? Can we trust them?

Comment: Both appear to have trial downloads, wouldn't you want to own this knowledge as opposed to trusting people on the internet?

Comment: I've never used them (I only use **real** databases), but from what *I* have read, the HXTT is pretty good.

Comment: @BalusC - Unfortunetelly this time this our only alternative is Microsoft Access (it's not our choice) :(

Comment: @Nick Veys - We know that. But we also want to know other people's opinion about it.

Answer (score 2):

If the databases are in Access 2000 format you could take a look at Jackcess: http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/

Comment: We take a look at that, but theres a problem: it doesn't accept SQL queries. We have to iterate over records instead of just writing SQL against the database.

But it's an option. 
Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

We bought the StelsMDB driver and the result (and the pricing) is good.

Our application is not very complex but enough to break the ODBC-JDBC bridge.

Comment: How about the ammount of data? Does it work well with databases which carry something like 10.000 to 50.000 records?